# Symfony4 webprofiler 404

Tags: php, symfony, localhost, symfony4

I've just setted up a fresh Symfony 4 project but when I navigate to the "public" folder the webprofiler shows up with the following message:

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Open the web profiler.
```

When I click on "Open the web profiler" I get the following error:

```
Error 404, Object not found
```

The path which is not found is in this case:

```
http://localhost/test-project/public/_profiler/4d2f65
```

Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Have you check the logs?

Comment: i got this issue when there is an error, such that your request does not lead to a response. so the code breaks at some point, means die or fatal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting up a Symfony4/Flex app from scratch, it might not have the profiler installed.

```
composer require profiler --dev
```

You may also need to follow the [webserver-config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) to enable mod_rewrite in Apache, or the equivalent in Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Test it with a server.

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

After that navigate to:

http://localhost:8000/_profiler